# Hive managed tables are not drop on azure data lake store

Tags: azure, hive, hiveql, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

I recently discover what I call a bug and I'd be sure it's a bug.

We work on an azure platform with HDInsight 3.6 with two separates storages : a blobstorage and a data lake store. 
For most part of our work we use Hive.

From what we know when you drop a managed table the data under this table are drop too. 
To be sure of this we tried this :

```
CREATE TABLE test(id String) PARTITIONED BY (part String) STORED AS ORC ;
INSERT INTO TABLE PARTITION(part='part1') VALUES('id1') ; 
INSERT INTO TABLE PARTITION(part='part2') VALUES('id2') ; 
INSERT INTO TABLE PARTITION(part='part3') VALUES('id3') ;
```

These queries are executed on the *default* database i.e on the blob storage.
The data are well stored under the location of the table *test* : if we check we have three directories **part=*** with files under them.

Then i drop the table :

```
DROP TABLE test ;
```

If we check the database directory there is no more directory named *test* so the data are well dropped and we expect this to be the correct hive behavior.

And now is the trick : For our work we use databases located on a datalake store and when we use this code :

```
use database_located_on_adl ; 
CREATE TABLE test(id String) PARTITIONED BY (part String) STORED AS ORC ;
INSERT INTO TABLE PARTITION(part='part1') VALUES('id1') ; 
INSERT INTO TABLE PARTITION(part='part2') VALUES('id2') ; 
INSERT INTO TABLE PARTITION(part='part3') VALUES('id3') ; 
DROP TABLE test ;
```

The table are well created, the data are well stored BUT the data are not dropped on the `DROP TABLE` command ...

Am I missing something ? Or is this a normal behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone see this old post and have the same issue : Our problem was that we missed the write right on the hive trash (**/user/*hiveUserName*/.Trash** HDFS folder).

Hope this can help !

Comment: Currently running into this issue. What do you mean by "missed the write"?